# Fetch the latest record in the table containing particular entry in spring jpa

Tags: java, sql, spring-data-jpa

I have a `Student` POJO and am trying to fetch the latest `Student` record from the table for the input class entered by the user. I know `findTopByIdDesc` can be used for the latest record but how can I fetch the latest record for a particular column value. Is there any JPA implementation or do I have to write a custom query to do this?

Here is my POJO:

```
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "student_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="student_seq",allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name="key_ring_id",insertable =false,nullable = false,updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name ="class")
    private String class;
}
```

For example if there are 10 students in class A & 10 in B. I need fetch the latest entry for class A.

Comment: look for CDC in SQL..might help you

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any JPA implementation or do I have to write a custom query to do this?

Spring Data JPA does not provide any special facilities for this kind of query. You need to write a custom query.

Side note: JPA implementations are things like Hibernate and EclipseLink. Spring Data JPA is not a JPA implementation but is build on top of JPA.

Answer (score 0):

You must write a custom query.

```
@Query(value="select max(id) from student where class=:className", nativeQuery=true)
Long getMaxIdForClass(@Param("className") String className);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write this custom query :

```
@Query(value="select top 1 * from student where class=:className", nativeQuery=true)
Student getLastestEntryForClass(@Param("className") String className);
```

**Logic :** You have to fetch all the students with the className "A" and then, you've to return first entry from that students. Hence, I'm using TopTop 1.

**Note :** Top 1 is used for sql server. If you are using mysql, then you have to use limit 1 and if you are using oracle, you have to use rownum<=1.

Refer this link - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp